# What is the ⎋ key

Tags: ide, intellij-idea

I'm new to IntelliJ and I saw a start-up tip that said, "The ⎋ key in any tool window moves the focus to the editor."  However, I don't know what the ⎋ key is.  I've been programming a long time.  Is it possible there's a key on my keyboard that I've missed all these years?

Comment: I don't own Mac, but it sounds like [Esc] does the same job on PCs. Do you have [Esc]?

Comment: Yes, `⎋` is the escape key, which is much more likely to be labeled `esc` on a Mac, just like on a PC. It is quite weird to refer to it as `⎋`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

<kbd>⎋</kbd> relates to **Escape** on Macintosh keyboards.  [Here is some documentation showing such.](http://guides.macrumors.com/Image:224px-Mac_keyboard_symbols.jpg)